# Error while running jar from command prompt

Tags: java, exception, cmd, program-entry-point

I'm using NetBeans IDE to code a java program. When I run the program from NetBeans it works perfectly but when I run it from command prompt I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaapplication/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javaapplication.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: javaapplication.Main. Program will exit.
```

I used another program (myEclipse) to build the program but the exact thing happened, I'm only able to run the program from the IDE and not command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, is `javaapplication.Main` meant to be the main class? If not, it's probably a mistake in the manifest file.

If it *is* meant to be the main class, look inside the jar file (e.g. by extracting it). Look for a directory called javaapplication which should have a file called Main.class in.

*One* of those two things is wrong, but we can't really tell what it is from here - only you can.

Comment: Thank You, I just created another project, copy & pasted the code & now, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when your MANIFEST.MF file is not correct. It is located in your *.jar file.

An example from one of my projects:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 14.2-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin.jar
Main-Class: at.package.to.main.class.MainClass
```

For more Information see here:
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_file

To change your MANIFEST.MF file should fix your problem.

**EDIT:** in response to "Jon Skeet": I'm assuming that you have a class with the

```
public static void main(String args[]){ ... }
```

method. If you don't have a mainclass - forget my answer and create a Main class ;-)